# PowerBI - DAX help needed

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a SaleSummary table that looks like this:

[SaleSummary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp8MP.png)

I would like to create a measure that sums up the SaleAmount of the latest SaleEvent (in the example provided SaleEventId=3) only where the ProductId existed in the previous **selected** SaleEventId. I have a slicer for SaleEvents and in this example I selected SaleEvent=1 and SaleEvent=3 so what I'm expecting is 110 as only the product ids 1 and 2 existed in SaleEvent 1.

I'm quite new to DAX and I got stuck with this, if anybody could help I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like this

### Data

| SalesEventld | Productld | SalesAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 3 | 35 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 2 | 60 |
| 3 | 3 | 70 |

## Steps

1. Get the Max `SalesEventId` of the selected items.
2. Get the Max `SalesEventId` excluding the calculation above.
3. To avoid any blanks when one SalesEventId is selected, I've added an `IF` statement to avoid that.
   When only one SalesEventId is selected defaults to `Step 1`.
4. Get the `ProductIds` using the `SalesEventId` from the step above.
5. Calculate the sales amount using the `ProductIds` from the step above and the `SalesEventId` from `Step 1`.

### DAX Calculation: Measure

```
Sales Amount = 
// Get the MAX Sales Event ID
VAR _MaxSalesEventId =
    MAX ( Data[SalesEventld] )
    
// Get the Max Sales Event ID excluding the one calculated above.
VAR _PreviousSalesEventId =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Data[SalesEventld] ),
        Data[SalesEventld] < _MaxSalesEventId,
        VALUES ( Data[SalesEventld] )
    ) 

// If only one SalesEventID is selected, retrieve the SalesEventID from the 1st step.
VAR _PreviousSalesEventId_AvoidBlanks =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( _PreviousSalesEventId ),
        _MaxSalesEventId,
        _PreviousSalesEventId
    ) 

// Get the ProductIds
VAR _ProductIds =
    SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( Data, Data[SalesEventld] = _PreviousSalesEventId_AvoidBlanks ), [Productld] ) 

// Calculate sales amount
VAR _SalesAmount =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Data[SalesAmount] ),
        Data[Productld] IN _ProductIds,
        Data[SalesEventld] = _MaxSalesEventId
    )
RETURN
    _SalesAmount
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: That worked like a treat, thank you so much, you are a DAX genius!